# ASP.NET 5 Class Library - Nuget package Web.Config transform

Tags: c#, nuget-package, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015, web.config-transform

I've created an ASP.NET 5 Class Library using the new project structure provided by Microsoft.  I can build the project and host it on a personal Nuget Feed just fine.  The only problem is, I would like for this package to insert a key into the destination project Web.config file, and it is not cooperating.

Building the project results in two files:

> ../artifacts/bin/{Project}/Debug/{Project}.nupkg
>      ../artifacts/bin/{Project}/Debug/{Project}.symbols.nupkg

**{Project}.nupkg** is what I am publishing to the hosted Nuget feed.

I've followed the [Nuget docs](https://docs.nuget.org/create/transforming-configuration-files-using-dottransform-files) on how to do this to no avail.

My `web.config.transform` file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Test Key" value="Test Value" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

When installed in a project, the web.config file remains unchanged.

The project structure of the ASP.NET 5 class library doesn't align exactly with the Nuget specs (e.g. it does not have **content**, **lib**, or **build** directories).  Could that be what is causing the issue?

**EDIT**
I'd like to use this Nuget package in an older (.Net 4.5) project. Given that ASP.NET 5 is still pretty new, I don't yet have any projects that would make use of its new structure yet (I.e. project.json). That being said, I would like to make the package backwards compatible with older (pre ASP.NET 5 projects) and newer ones (that leverage the JSON file structure) if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, NuGet transforms are not supported in ASP.NET 5. If you give more details about your scenario, we might be able to see if there is an alternative.

Also, you should avoid using web.config. The new configuration system based on JSON files. (xml is still supported, though)

Comment: Thank you for the information. The problem is, I'd like to use this Nuget package in an older project.  Given that ASP.NET 5 is still pretty new, I don't yet have any projects that would make use of its new structure yet (I.e. project.json).

That being said, I would like to make the package backwards compatible with older (pre ASP.NET 5 projects) and newer ones (that leverage the JSON file structure) if possible. 

The reason I need to do this at all is because the package I am creating has some configuration options that are being read from web.config in the appSettings node.

Comment: Is it possible to design the code that needs the setting from web.config to throw an exception with an actionable error message? Basically, telling the user that the setting is missing.

Comment: This could be done, but how would I design the code to support ASP.NET 5 projects? that is, I am of the understanding that **ConfigurationManager** is somewhat deprecated, so I'd have to pull the app settings from somewhere else for those types of projects.